# App suddenly requires app.config

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an application MyApp.exe that has been running for a while. I am not sure what I have changed but suddenly it is requiring MyApp.exe.config to be in the same folder. It was running normally and saving settings in the %appsettings% or wherever it saved.

How can I revert it back to not require the presence of MyApp.exe.config n the same folder?

Comment: Cannot say if it is a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833237/is-app-config-required-in-net-4-0-c-sharp-projects?rq=1). Please check

Comment: Explain "requiring". What happens if it's missing?

Comment: @CodeCaster I get an exception "Configuration system failed to initialize"

Comment: And what is the innerexception?

Comment: ---------------------------

---------------------------
Inner: Unrecognized configuration section userSettings. (C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\MA\MyApp.exe_StrongName_4woblyyuyv3ue3i4wq45jpmm0qelqvda\0.0.0.30\user.config line 3)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
@CodeCaster

Comment: Can you post (the relevant part in) the app.config?

Comment: You have a bad user.config file, perhaps you changed the settings too much without increasing your [AssemblyVersion].  Delete the file.