# C# Console application keeps creating a Configuration FIle

Tags: c#, config

I am new to C#. I am an admin, not a programmer, but I am starting to see how being able to write some console apps could help me with automation. So I wrote one and it works well.

Here is the issue. Every time I execute the exe file for the console application, it generates a .config file. There isn't really anything in the config file.  just a few lines. ***How do I make it stop.*** The Program.cs is really just calling SCOM's SDK to put a machine into maintenance mode.

Developed in: c# in visual studio 2013
.net version used - 3.5

Comment: Are you sure that it's every time you *run* the app, or any time you *build* the app? If it's when you build, there's probably an App.config file in your Visual Studio project. Just delete it, unless there's actually relevant configuration there.

Comment: Well, if it is already there, then it will not create it again. So, in my project, there is an app.config file, which I think is there by default. I don't have any special configuration. I deleted it, and then rebuilt, and then executed my newly built exe file again, but it still creates the configuration file in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: "Well, if it is already there, then it will not create it again." When? When you run, or when you build? What if you build, run, delete the file, then run again - with no "rebuild" part?

Comment: Ok. forget the build. I take the ONE .EXE file after build. I copy the ONE EXE file to a new machine. I execute it. BOOM - creates a .config file. I run it again, it does NOT recreate the config file because it still exists. I delete the config file. Execute again, and it creates it once again.

Comment: Right. So that sounds like it's something in the code that does it. But we can't really tell what, without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. But assuming commenter Jon's guess is correct, and that you really mean that when you *build* your executable, a .config file is generated, then his advice is correct: just remove the "App.config" file from your project, and no .config file will be generated. The "App.config" file is the template for the .config file; at build time, the file is copied to the output directly, using the executable name and the extension .config.

Please note that this may or may not be safe to do. It *probably* is. However, some C# projects have configuration information in the .config file that is actually needed. Please see [Is app.config required in .Net 4.0 C# projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3833237) for more details on that question.

Finally, I will suggest that for simple automation tasks, you may find other tools more appropriate that even a simple C# console program. The two I use most commonly are PowerShell and plain old batch files, though there are a number of other similar scripting-style automation tools that work on Windows (including a variety of *nix-style shells that are compiled for Windows).

Comment: There is more than one way to do this, but I chose c# because I am learning it. Yes, a config file is created when I build it. But, if I take the .exe and copy it to a completely different machine, it will execute, but it will create a config file. There really isn't anything in it, just the config xml skeleton.

Comment: @BrodyKilpatrick: Can you provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? (Is it possible this is part of the SCOM SDK's behaviour?)

Comment: @BrodyKilpatrick: if I create a blank console program project, compile it, and copy the .exe -- without the .config file -- to a new location, it does _not_ create a .config file when I run the program from that new location. Unfortunately, your question does not provide enough detail to understand what is going on in your scenario. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hmm, you know what, that is a good point. I will create a whole new solution and project and paste my code in. I don't know why I haven't thought of that. I will let you know what happens.